# Get the attributes given condition from different functions

Tags: python, iteration

I make a project to create equations using combination of numbers and mathematical operator to get the expected number.

GIVEN :

```
time to create the equation, set of number, set of operator, a goal
```

FUNCTIONS include:

- create sequence of number and operator
- evaluate the sequence (to get the result)
- mutate the sequence
- get the best sequence, where result of the sequence = goal

PROBLEM:
I need to get the `sequence` and `time` where `result` equal to `goal`.

Below is the complete script of my last trial:

```
self.goal = 22
self.time = 4
self.sequence = sequence
self.BestSequence = []

def step(self):
    while self.time > 0:
        self.time -= 1
        self.createSeqeuence ()  #create sequence
        self.evaluate()          #evaluate sequence
        self.allResult.append(self.evaluate()) #make list of result within time
        self.mutateSequence()    #modify sequence
    self.getBestSequence() #after time = 0, get the best sequence from allResult where result = goal
    print(self.result, self.BestSequence,self.time) #show

def createSeqeuence (self)
def evaluate(self)
def changeSequence(self)
```

RESULT:

```
time     sequence                  result
1      ['12','+','8']                20
2      ['10','+','8']                18
3      ['5','*','3']                 15
4      ['10','*','2','+','2']        22
```

PROBLEM >>>>

```
def getBestSequence(self):
    if self.leadTime > 0:
        for j in self.allResult:
            self.BestSequence = [k for k in self.sequence if j == self.goal]
            return
```

I expect to get:  `[22, ['10','*','2','+','2'], 4 ]`, but I got: `[10 None 0]`. **Note** that the functions don't always get a sequence where the result = goal within the time. So `def getBestSequence ()` may return `[]`

Please advice

Comment: You need to provide reproducible examples. Using fragments from a class definition in this case, with calls to undefined functions, just doesn't give enough information

Comment: And why is this tagged "pass-by-reference". Those semantics are not supported in Python.